# Joining Points and Polygons

Tags: point, arcgis-9.3, error

I am new at using ArcGIS 9.3.1 and am having trouble joining data. I have a shapefile of census tract polygons and a separate file of points that are crimes in Chicago in 2010. The crime points were part of a separate Excel file that I uploaded and converted into a point shapefile.

I now am trying to see how many of the crimes occurred within each census tract but when I try to do "join" it gives me the error: `Can't create output feature class`.

Why am I getting this?

Is there another way to do this?

I've tried everything I can find on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what join method you used, however since you have two GIS layers I would suggest for you to use [Spatial Join](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Spatial%20Join%20%28Analysis%29).

1. Target feature should be your crime point layer
2. Once data set is joined, you can [summarize](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Summarizing%20data%20in%20a%20table) the census tract name field (within the point feature table) to get the crime count per census tract

Answer (score 1):

What is the output feature class that you are trying to create?  I would say that you are probably trying to write to a location that does not exist or that you do not have write access to.